# Tracking eyes motion real time

Tags: python, performance, optimization, real-time

Helloo guys, I`ve wrote a code in python that detect eyes motion but It works just for video file.

What should I change to make It to detect the motion eyes in the real time through the web cam ?

There is the code:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("eye_recording.flv")

while True:
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret is False:
    break

roi = frame[269: 795, 537: 1416]
rows, cols, _ = roi.shape
gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (7, 7), 0)

_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

for cnt in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(roi, (x + int(w/2), 0), (x + int(w/2), rows), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(roi, (0, y + int(h/2)), (cols, y + int(h/2)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    break

cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)
cv2.imshow("gray roi", gray_roi)
cv2.imshow("Roi", roi)
key = cv2.waitKey(30)
if key == 27:
    break
```

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

That's it